# How can i explode a value in database and use it in select query?

Tags: php, database, laravel, mysqli, phpmyadmin

So, i have a checkbox in my blog for input category where the category value can be multiple. I insert them into database using implode function. Now i want my blog filter by categories if i use the below query it only gets where the category id is single. How can i fetch data where category id has multiple value. And it should be visible in every category it was checked.

```
public function getPublishedBlogInfoByCategory($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE category_id = '$id' ORDER BY id DESC";
    if(mysqli_query(Database::dbConnection(), $sql)){
        $queryResult = mysqli_query(Database::dbConnection(), $sql);
        return $queryResult;
    }else{
        die('Query problem'.mysqli_error(Database::dbConnection()));
    }
}
```

Here's i'm calling that function

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$blog = new App\classes\Blog;
$app = new App\classes\Application;

$queryResultCategory = $blog->getAllPublishedCategory();

$id = $_GET['id'];
$queryResult = $app->getPublishedBlogInfoByCategory($id);
$queryResultCategoryName = $app->getBlogCategoryName($id);
$categoryName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResultCategoryName);

$queryResultEvent = $app->getLimitedPublishedEvent();
```

?>

Comment: This would be a great place for a pivot table instead: have a table called `blogs_categories` with a blog_id and category_id.

Comment: i have table named blog_categories from where the value of checkbox (category_id) is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with aynber that a pivot table would probably fit your needs better than a string column with multiple category ids concatenated together. However, to answer your question, rather than

```
= '$id'
```

which only matches if the entirety of the field matches the entirety of $id, you probably just need to use

```
LIKE '%$id%'
```

which treats the % as wildcards to match any number of characters before or after the $id

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_category_pivot` (
    `blog_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `category_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`, `category_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `blog_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`blog_id`) REFERENCES `blogs` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `category_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
);
```

Then to use the data you can just do a select from blogs and join the blog_category_pivot table to check if it has a given category. If you want to list the categories of a blog you already have an id for you can do a select name from categories joining the blog_category_pivot table on blog_id = $blog_id and category_id = categories.id

Comment: Hey Thanks, that's worked. Really appreciate this :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped. Though if possible, I would again recommend using a pivot table instead.

Comment: (Edited to add a bit of explanation as I realized my answer was rather bare-bones)  :)

Comment: Actually i don't have much idea about pivot table. Can you give me any link or something that i can learn about that?

Comment: I did a search to find a good tutorial, but everything seemed to be about pivoting data in an existing table, so I'll add to my answer some information about how to do it.

Comment: Good luck with the pivot table then! And I'll keep an eye here if you need to ask any questions about it. Also, feel free to mark as accepted if you're happy with an answer :)